# Good books for differentiation (I ask because differentiation might not be the best word for it)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm stuck because ... while the module is called "differentiation" it actually isn't. Searching for that gives results polluted with the single variable case.

I have attached the syllabus but I don't want to tick those boxes, I want to know about the subject (I've already encountered the Jacobian matrix, Taylor's theorem in the multivariable case, implicit function theorem, but from no one book).

http://alec-teal.co.uk/ma225_syllabus.pdf

I really hate posting a syllabus and going what book, I just want search terms really. Like what should I be looking for if I went to the library, "differentiation" is not it.

Also suppose I wanted to find assignments from other universities. My one seems to be the only one that called it "differentiation" what module would I search for to find more question sheets?

I am sorry for this vague question, SE is even warning me it might be closed, but Ted isn't in the chatroom.

Answer (score 1):

Spivak's [Calculus on Manifolds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805390219) is very good. I think it's what you're looking for.

If you want to search for yourself, usually these topics are titled "multivariable calculus." You also might try reading up on Differential Geometry.